# Unable to read files which are greater than 2GB

Tags: php, video-streaming, streaming, filereader

I am using this below code to stream a movie on my localhost. The movie which is lesser then 2GB works fine but when it comes to movie greater than 2gb then the movie doesn't play.

Please help me what should I do to read larger files.

This is the code I am using for streaming movie

```
<?php

//Determine file path according to extension
if (!isset($_GET['ext']) || $_GET['ext'] == 'mp4') {
    $path ='movies/'.$_GET['movie'];
}


$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime = $finfo->file($path);
header('Content-Type: ' . $mime);

$size = filesize($path);


if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {


    list($specifier, $value) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']);
    if ($specifier != 'bytes') {
        header('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request');
        return;
    }


    list($from, $to) = explode('-', $value);
    if (!$to) {
        $to = $size - 1;
    }


    $fp = fopen($path, 'rb');
    if (!$fp) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
        return;
    }


    header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');


    header('Content-Length: ' . ($to - $from));


    header("Content-Range: bytes {$from}-{$to}/{$size}");


    fseek($fp, $from);


    while(true){

        if(ftell($fp) >= $to){
            break;
        }


        echo fread($fp, 8192);

        // Flush do buffer
        ob_flush();
        flush();
    }
}
else {

    header('Content-Length: ' . $size);


    readfile($path);
}
```

I have hosted the files on localhost using xammpp as a server.

Answer (score -1):

This could have different reasons.

fopen() reads a file into your RAM. So the limitation seems to come from there.

First, make sure you have min 4GB installed in your system.
If you need more also make sure you dont use a Win 32-Bit system since this only supports up to 4GB ram.

Then you can try to increase the `memory_limit` of PHP. Open the xampp/php/php.ini file and change the `memory_limit` to what ever you need OR set the ini value directly in your php file like this

`ini_set(”memory_limit”,”16M”);`

Hope this helps. For a more specific answer it would be helpful if you have any error message.